# How to install xserver-xorg in unattended mode?

Tags: debian, xorg, apt, unattended

When I install xserver-xorg package on Debian9, I have to manually input the package configuration for keyboard layout

[image: Package Configuration]

How can I skip this step, or preconfigured the keyboard layout, so I can install the package in unattended mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` option:

```
# DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -q -y package_name
```

Or

```
# export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# apt install -q -y package_name
```

Use `sudo` if it is already installed.The installed package can reconfigured later through:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure package_name
```